# Python:Storing path in variable; Argument Error

Tags: python, path, invalid-argument

```
path = input("Enter the path")
book = xlrd.open_workbook(path)
```

After giving path and running program, I am getting the following error:

OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '"D:\\\shreyatest1.xlsx"'

Path is: "D:\\shreyatest1.xlsx"

Comment: Are you inputting it with double slashes?

Comment: Yes. And yet i am getting the error.

Comment: Dont do that, while inputting, use single slash only.

Comment: No luck :\ same error

Comment: Have you tried @Mureinik answer? That is what I meant.

Comment: Then what did you try as a second attempt after my comment, which didnt work.

Comment: I removed one slash and used only single slash. Which didn't work. It works when I input the path as it is and not in quotes.

Comment: So, another lesson to learn is that you never input something to input() in quotes, otherwise even the quotes will be considered as part of the string inputted.

Comment: Yess. Thank you for making me realise that!

Answer (score 1):

The `\\` character is how python represents an escaped `\` in a string literal. When inputting a string from the console, there's no need (read: it's wrong) to use this notation. Just input the path as you see it - `D:\shreyatest1.xlsx`.

Comment: Worked. Thanks a lot! :)